# Spring profiles not being set with gradle system property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm running the following command

```bash
./gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=ci build
```

but when I do the profile is not set

```
     INFO - The following 3 profiles are active: "test", "test-feign", "dev" : e1.configuration.feign.DevExchangeOAuth2FeignRequestInterceptorCalledTest
```

those are being set by `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active = dev
spring.profiles.include= test
spring.profiles.group.ci[0] = ci-feign
spring.profiles.group.test[0] = test-feign
```

why is this? and how can I fix it. Note: I cannot set the env var for reasons stupid in corporate environment. Also this is a monorepo.

**UPDATE** I felt like this was obvious, but I only want to set this in CI, not all the time. And it should respect configuration cache

Answer (score 0):

System properties are only set for a single JVM.

You are setting the property for the JVM, which executes the Gradle Build itself.

Your tests, however, will be running in a different JVM (with different system properties).

Your can set system properties for your unit tests in your build.gradle as follows:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'ci'
}
```

Comment: but I obviously only want to have that set in CI... this would set it all the time

Comment: Then you could just set the systemProperty for the test task based on a grade property